# Extract numbers from poker cards

Tags: image-processing

I want to develop an application that, given an image of several poker cards, is able to tell what numbers are on those cards.  I have never done any image-processing before, so I wonder how I should get started.  Any thoughts will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on how the images look like. For example if the images are taken from say a mobile cam and they have to be pre-processed before you can do OCR.

I've used Tesseract ( https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) before to do OCR and it works ok for printed text. But does poorly without training on images from a mobile phone.  You can also you some 3rd party paid API if you dont want to go through all the work yourself.

Also some valuable advice I got were to

1. Keep only text part in the image. (Eliminate unnecessary lines/
   noise).
2. If the text is vertical or oriented at some angle, align the text
   region in horizontal direction.

Comment: The images will indeed be taken from a mobile device.  The cam should be around 5 mega-pixel.  In any case, could you specify what you meant by "pre-process"?  Many thanks!

Comment: The steps 1 & 2 I mentioned are two pre-processing steps that can help with image recognition.

Comment: I might be missing something, but OCR is the technique you use to recognize text, right?  So how would I `keep only text part in the image` before doing OCR?

Comment: Im not big into OCR, just played around with it a bit but cropping the image was one of things I did to try to train the tesseract engine. Imho the easiest way to go about is using a paid 3rd party API. Also I dont know if the Google Goggles API is public yet, but it does a great job in OCR.